# How to avoid the -Inf log-likelihood problem in mle function from stat4 package?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, mle

I want to maximize the log-likelihood function to fit some data, but the mle function stop with this error when the log-likelihood is -Inf.

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
>     L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

The code is:

```
  ll <- function(shape, scale) {
  x <-
    c(2,  12,  61,   9,  25, 110,   7,  27,  17,  15,  11,  17,  15,  25,   0)
  - sum(dgamma(x, shape, scale, log = TRUE))
  }

    m <- stats4::mle(ll, start = list(shape = 2.15, scale = 2), method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.01, 0.01))
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem in a clean manner?

Comment: After trying your code, it seems like it treats `0` as a non-finite value.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the mle algorithm try some parameters (shape, scale) such that the log-lik of zero given such parameters is -Inf. I feel this situation could be very usual, so I think there should be an usual way for avoiding it...

Comment: The density at `x = 0` is zero if shape > 1. The log(0) is `-Inf`.

Comment: also, note that if shape<1 the density at `x=0` is `Inf` (and hence the log-density is `Inf`); `x=0` is only well-behaved if shape is *exactly* 1 (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141317/fitting-gamma-distribution-to-data-set-with-one-zero-observation ; no answer, but one useful comment)

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker . Actually I am trying to fit a curve with lot of zeros, so maybe I should try another distribution. I tried an exponential density and it works very well along the support but underestimate zeros. Look this another question as I need a little bit of help as I am very stuck: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146378/what-density-distribution-could-be-used-for-time-delays